# Conditional statement for attribute in an array

Tags: php, arrays, magento, if-statement

I have an array that gets imported daily. For the specific field 'special_price' i only want it to import into Main Website > Main Website Store > **Default Store View**

Default store view = 1

```
  protected function _getFieldNames()
        {
            return array(
                'company_number',
                'sku',
                'style_number',
                'name',
                'div_code',
                'div_desc',
                'color_code',
                'color',
                'size_type',
                'size',
                'price',
                'weight',
                'description',
                'special_price',
                'tax_code',
            );
        }
```

I can instantiate the class like so:

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
```

My question is how to parse that one specific field for only the default store and let the other updates run as usual. I assume i'm using an IF statement.

Is it possible to just `unset()` that item based upon an IF statement?

Comment: $websites = Mage::app()->getWebsites();

$default = $websites[1]->getDefaultStore();

Comment: How do i incorporate this into the array? @GoatHater

Comment: not sure, your code sample was confusing in the context presented, thats why i answered with a comment instead of an answer.  But that will give you the default store.

Comment: Is it possible to just unset() that item based upon an IF statement? @GoatHater

Comment: you might be able to do something along the lines of:  if(Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId() === Mage::app()->getWebsites()[1]->getDefaultStore()->getStoreId()) return array(without special_price);

Comment: I think you may be on to something.